# RSpec -- lambda usage

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, lambda, rspec

Can someone please explain the difference between the following methods to me?

```
it "should create a user" do
    lambda do
        post :create, :user => @attr
    end.should change(User, :count).by(1)
end
```

That is the method as it currently stands.  Could this also be achieved with the method below?

```
it "should create a user" do
    post :create, :user => @attr
    response.should change(User, :count).by(1)
end
```

Are these effectively the same?  Or does the second not work?  Because the tutorial I'm following seems to use `response` whenever possible, yet did not do it in the above case.  Can someone please explain the difference between the two above methods, how lambda and RSpec's response work?  Thanks!

Comment: The lambda method is stating that the overall action changes the User count by +1 where as the second method is stating the the response changes the User count by +1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The lambda form is equivalent to doing this, if the test database is empty:

```
User.count.should == 0
post :create, :user => @attr
User.count.should == 1
```

I believe that calling `change` without supplying a block, as you show in the second example, will generate an error.

The lambda form is used to wrap a section of code which can be used for setting an expectation in a more convenient way then testing with before and after conditions. In more recent versions of RSpec you'll also see this done with `expect`:

```
expect {
  post :create, :user => @attr
}.to change(User, :count).by(1)
```